# Encrypt in php and decrypt in swift

Tags: php, xcode, encryption, swift, rncryptor

i'm coding an API in php to comunicate with an iOS App.

I would like to encrypt this data in php, transmit them and so decrypt in the iOS app (swift language)

To encrypt i php no problems:

```
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

But when i receive the data in iOS how can i decrypt them?

I saw [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) that, of course, is written in objective-c and it could be integrated in a swift project, but when i add the files to the project x-code doesn't asks me if i want to integrate them and it doesn't make the bridging header.

Does someone have already had this problem or knows an alternative way to decrypt data in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because Xcode didn't prompt you doesn't mean you can't make a bridging header. Just add a file to your project named "-Bridging-Header.h" (replace  with your project's name, of course.

Next look in build settings for the Objective-C Bridging Header field and set it to your header's name. Then you just import all the Objective-C headers you need in your bridging header.

Make sure you add the bridging header in the root directory of your project. Xcode will probably try to add it in a subdirectory.